# Android Kivy JsonStore data.json does not persist across upgrades

Tags: android, json, kivy, store

I'm using the JsonStore with a Kivy app

```
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
stored_data = JsonStore('data.json')
```

On my PC, the store is preserved even if I rebuild the program.

On my android phone, reloading the same apk file keeps the data, but any change to the program (and rebuild) seems to wipe the stored data.

Am I doing something wrong, how can I keep the data through upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you write your files to the folder where your app is located. You should write them to /sdcard and also give the write permissions:

```
from jnius import autoclass
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
...
# request a permission from user
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
...
# path to sdcard (external storage that user have access to)
Environment = autoclass('android.os.Environment')
sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

So, after that you can make your folder there, something like:

```
if not os.path.exists(sdpath + '/yourappname'):
    os.makedirs(sdpath + '/yourappname')
```

And save your files there, they won't be deleted while reinstalling the app anymore.

P.S. don't forget to add pyjnius to requirements in the buildozer spec file!